# jQuery outside events plugin not funcitoning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have downloaded the jQuery outside events plugin as Sarfraz suggested, which seems really great, except, I cannot appear to get it functioning correctly.

Here is my code that I'm trying to call it with:

```
$("#player").bind( "clickoutside", function(event){
  if($('#player').is(':visible')) {
    $('#player').slideToggle(500);
  }
});
```

I don't understand why this isn't working.

I think it may have a problem with this jQuery snippet form my other jQuery file:

```
$('#text_music').click(function() {
  $('#jplayer').slideToggle(500);
});
```

But I'm not entirely sure.

In this context, `#player` is the `<div>` which contains my jPlayer plugin code, and `#text_music` is just the image which has text reading `Music`, which, upon click, should slideToggle the `#player` `<div>`.

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

You can see the implementation (*attempted* implementation, rather) at http://www.marioplanet.com

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're slide toggling two different elements. Try changing `#player` in the callback of your first block of code to `#jplayer`:

```
$("#player").bind( "clickoutside", function(event){ 
  if($('#jplayer').is(':visible')) { 
    $('#jplayer').slideToggle(500); 
  } 
});
```

I tried running this snippet in Firebug's console immediately after loading the page and then it behaved correctly.

Comment: Thanks!  Wow... Haha, I cannot believe that it was just that typo.. aghh! :)